# How to import svg files in public directory with react vite svgr

Tags: reactjs, svg, vite, svgr

How to use [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/docs/what-is-svgr/) with React's 'public' folder assets?

I'm using react + vite + svgr and my svg files are located in the "public" directory.
My project structure is

```
|
|- src
|- public
    |- icons
        |- svgs
            |- mySvg.svg
|- vite.config.ts
|- package.json
```

since public is outside of the src folder I get the error:

> Assets in public directory cannot be imported from JavaScript.
>
> If you intend to import that asset, put the file in the src directory, and use /src/assets/icons/svgs/mySvg.svg instead of /public/assets/icons/svgs/mySvg.svg.

**Clarification**:

- The solution of converting to `img` element with url is not good as I need to change svg properties.
- The solution of changing the folder from the `public` folder are not good in my
  case as I'd like to maintain the standard public folder as the folder
  for assets in order to receive built in supports from different
  libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't find / get a proper solution, so I'll post my work around as the solution for future developers (in hopes someone can supply a better one or create a better one from my solution):

SVGR has CLI support features that can be used in order to create a script that will generate react component for each *.svg file in the public folder

In your package.json file add the "update-icons" script:

```
"scripts":
    "start": ...,
    ...
    "update-icons": "chmod u+x scripts/icons/update-icons.sh && scripts/icons/update-icons.sh", <--- add this line
    ...
...
```

create template files for your generated components and index files at a folder to your liking (e.g. "src/assets/templates"):

```
// example for component template in file named "componentTemplate.ts"

import { Template } from "@svgr/babel-plugin-transform-svg-component";

export const defaultTemplate: Template = (variables, { tpl }) => {
    return tpl`
import type { SVGProps, ReactElement } from "react";

${variables.interfaces};

export default function ${variables.componentName}(${variables.props}): ReactElement {
  return (
      ${variables.jsx}
  );
};

`;
};

export default defaultTemplate;


// example for index template in file named indexTemplate.ts

export const formatExportName = (name: string): string => {
    if (/[-]/g.test(name) && /^\d/.test(name)) {
        return `Svg${pascalCase(name)}`;
    }

    if (/^\d/.test(name)) {
        return `Svg${name}`;
    }

    return pascalCase(name);
};

const defaultIndexTemplate: IndexTemplate = (paths: FileInfo[]) => {
    const exportEntries = paths.map(({ path: filePath }) => {
        const basename = path.basename(filePath, path.extname(filePath));
        const exportName = formatExportName(basename);

        return `export { default as Svg${exportName} } from './${basename}'`;
});

    return exportEntries.join("\n");
};
```

create a shell script file named, for example "update-icons.sh", under some dedicated folder (e.g. "scripts/icons/").

In the file content add the following

```
#!/bin/bash

# configure below variables according to your project specific needs
baseFolder=$(pwd)
dest=$baseFolder/src/assets/generated
src=$baseFolder/public/assets
templatesPath=src/assets/templates # you template files
templates=( componentTemplate indexTemplate )
folders=( svgs ) # you can specify a list of folders here instead of generating all files in the public folder
BLUE="\033[0;34m" # this is used to make the console output prettier
NC="\033[0m" # this is used to make the console output prettier

rm -r "$dest" # remove existing files from the destination folder that contains the generated svg React components

# my project uses ESNext so I need to first transpile the related template files to CommonJS (for SVGR)
echo -e "${BLUE}Transpiling templates${NC}"
for template in "${templates[@]}"
do
  npx tsc --module commonjs --skipLibCheck true "./$templatesPath/$template.ts"
  cp "$baseFolder/$templatesPath/$template.js" "$baseFolder/$templatesPath/$template.cjs"
  rm "$baseFolder/$templatesPath/$template.js"
done
echo "Done"
echo ""

# this is the main part of the solution
echo -e "${BLUE}Generating React components${NC}"
for folder in "${folders[@]}"
do
      npx @svgr/cli --typescript --filename-case kebab --no-dimensions --index-template "./${templatesPath}/indexTemplate.cjs" --template "./${templatesPath}/componentTemplate.cjs" --out-dir "$dest/${folder}" "$src/${folder}"
done

# remove redundant CommonJS files
for template in "${templates[@]}"
do
  rm "$baseFolder/$templatesPath/$template.cjs"
done
```

Now just run "npm run update-icons"
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to Move your SVG files to the "src" directory under a suitable location, such as "src/assets/icons/svgs" (or any other appropriate location within the "src" directory).

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. there are many related posts that solve the issue like you suggested, however I'm looking for a solution that will avoid changing the location of my assets, as the public folder is the correct location for them, in my case.

Comment: Sure, in this case you can create a workaround by dynamically loading the SVG files using their URL.  Just use the SVG by specifying the path:  `<img src="/assets/icons/svgs/mySvg.svg" alt="My SVG" />`. In this case the assets folder are inside the public folder.

Comment: This is also a workaround I saw but in my case I need it as a component and not an image, so that I can change the SVG properties according to need

Comment: I've edited the question with said clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the `public` folder are copied to `dist` unchanged.
Try icons/svgs/mySvg.svg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm getting errors when doing so, since it does not exist there before the build process. The project serves multiple developers so I cannot add errors. Do you have a suggestion on how to solve the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. Right after setting up the Vite project, I implemented path aliases. However, resolving from the public folder resulted in the same failure.

I managed to solve the problem by following the instructions in the Vite documentation:

```
import reactLogo from '@assets/react.svg'
const viteLogo = new URL('@public/vite.svg', import.meta.url).href

<div>
    <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
      <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
    </a>
    <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
      <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
    </a>
```

[Asset import info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcYqd.png)

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory

Hope it helps

Comment: I actually saw it, but as stated, I'm changing the svg element styles properties. The img element obfuscates the svg elements, so it does not solve my particular use case...